# parallelogram card with css and bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, card

[image: How can i make card like this]

How can I make a card like this with css or bootsrap?

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to show your work than to search for answers to copy and paste here.

The below example below does not take responsive design into account, using bootstrap-4.

You can take it as reference and check the meaning of different class like `ml-3`, `shadow` from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<style>
  .diagonal-left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #deadee;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    margin: 20px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .diagonal {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #319b9e;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    margin: 20px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .diagonal>span {
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="ml-3 row">
    <div class="diagonal-left shadow"></div>
    <div class="diagonal shadow"><span>Title<br>123</span></div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not responsive in mobile mode um..

Comment: I encourage you to have a look on this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns. You can make it responsive simply adding bootstrap defined class such as ```col-(x)```.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **transform:skew();**
here is an exapmle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.parallelogram {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: skew(20deg);
    background: #555;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Parallelogram CSS</h2>
<div class="parallelogram"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

;